# find the word that appears the most at the beginning of a line from entire paragraph

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a paragraph and I want to know which word appears the most at the beginning of a line from all paragraph

for example:
paragraph:

```
Hello my name is X

Nice to meet you

Hello my name is Y
```

so Hello appears 2 times so i will output hello

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -v RS= '
  {word = tolower($1); n = ++count[word]}
  n > max {max_word = word; max = n}
  END {print max_word}'
```

Comment: all my text is lowercase sorry!  so what code now use??

Comment: This code will work fine if the input is all lower case.  But, if you want to ‘optimize’ it, change ```word = tolower($1)``` to ```word = $1```.

Answer (score 1):

Below command will give you the required most repeated word along with the count.

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below associate array method

```
awk 'NF{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x" appears "a[x]}}' | sort -k3 -nr | sed -n '1p'
```

output:

```
Hello appears 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not easy part... awk '{ print $1 }' myfile |uniq -c

Comment: maybe you needed `awk 'NF{ … }' infile| sort| uniq -c | sort -r|head -n1 | ... '`? what you currently answered doesn't do anyting just adding `1` in front of each first word in a line. also [single `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513007/72456) do the job then.