# find a pair of words that appear the most of the times together

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have 10 text files, in each file i have a chapter from a book, i want to find the pair of words that appear the most of the time together in a line i.e:

chapter1:

```
hello world good boy green sun

good green boy sun world hello
```

chapter2:

chapter3:

.....etc

Output wanted for chapter1:

```
hello world (alphabet order)
```

Comment: The output should have "boy green" also, right?

Comment: yes "boy green" also, didn't see

Comment: what about if you had a line like `Hello world Hello`? it should come in output? and how ? `Hello world` or `world Hello`?

Comment: hello world , and this will count for 2 to the pair "hello world" always alphabetical

Comment: how about `Hello\nworld\nHello`? `\n` is actual new-line character. please [edit] your question to answer for comments asking for clarifications

Comment: Ohhh, sounds this is a followup of your recent question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513006/72456

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
  {
    $0 = tolower($0)
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
      pair = $i"" < $(i+1) ? $i" "$(i+1) : $(i+1)" "$i
      c = ++count[pair]
      if (c > max) max = c
    }
  }
  END {
    for (pair in count)
      if (count[pair] == max)
        print pair
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Use `awk` to print each pair of words.
2. Use `perl` to sort the words in a pair ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511353)).
3. Use `sort` and `uniq -c` to count occurrences each pair.

---

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) { print tolower($i)" "tolower($(i+1)) }}' file \
| perl -ane '$,=" "; print sort @F; print "\n";' \
| sort | uniq -c | sort -b -k1nr -k2
```

Output:

```
  2 boy green
  2 hello world
  1 boy good
  1 boy sun
  1 good green
  1 good world
  1 green sun
  1 sun world
```

Comment: can not use perl or pipeline..

Comment: Why can't you, @John? Those are standard utilities on most Linux systems.

Comment: Yes, this kind of information should be in your question.